# Control glossaries fontsize

Tags: fontsize, fontspec, glossaries

What is the most convenient way to control the fontsize of the text printed by `\printglossary` from `glossaries` ? For example,

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[backend=biber,backref=true]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{example,
    author  = {Doe, John},
    title   = {Some things I did},
    year    = {2014},
    journal = {J.~Irrep. Res.},
    pages   = {1-10}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\footnotesize}
\usepackage[xindy,toc]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\begin{document}
\newacronym{cmp}{CMP}{Common Mid Point}
\glsaddall
\parencite{example}
\printbibliography
\printglossary
\end{document}
```

here, I can control the fontsize of `\printbibliography` with `\bibfont`. How to do this with `glossaries` ? Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this line in your preamble:

```
\renewcommand{\glossarypreamble}{\footnotesize}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[backend=biber,backref=true]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{example,
    author  = {Doe, John},
    title   = {Some things I did},
    year    = {2014},
    journal = {J.~Irrep. Res.},
    pages   = {1-10}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\footnotesize}
\usepackage[xindy,toc]{glossaries}
\renewcommand{\glossarypreamble}{\footnotesize}
\makeglossaries
\begin{document}
\newacronym{cmp}{CMP}{Common Mid Point}
\glsaddall
\parencite{example}
\printbibliography
\printglossary
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]